# jQuery Date: getFullMonth and getFullDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I would like to get the month and date of the actual date of today. So far I have this code:

```
var d = new Date();   

var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();
var day = d.getUTCDate();

var highestDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();

var fromDateString = year + "-" + month + "-01";
var toDateString = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

console.log(fromDateString + " - " + toDateString)
```

The only problem is that `getUTCDate()`/`getDate()` is not returning 01-31 but rather 1-31. That is causing the problem that I have only one number between 1-9 and not two like 01, 02, 03, 04, 05 and so on..

Same goes for the month. I only get 1-12 instead of 01-12 with `getMonth() + 1`. How can I get the current date and month in two digits instead of only one?

I already tried this but it isn't working because I have not Date format at the end:

```
if(month == 1){
    month = "0" + month;
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!
Thank you!

Comment: try `if(month.length == 1)`

Comment: `function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2);}`